# Allow another user to access my Oracle table

Tags: oracle

I would simply like to allow a colleague to view and edit the Database I've created.

I've tried:

```
GRANT ALL on FISHTABLE to CDEMARES;
```

and it returned `Grant succeeded` but nothing changed for him and he still wasn't able to view my table.

I also tried

```
GRANT SELECT smahala.fishtable to cdemares@sole.nefsc.noaa.gov;
```

but that failed with `SQL Error: ORA_00990: missing or invalid privilege`.

Is my issue that I don't have the administrative authority to allow someone else to view my Oracle table? Any advice is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It is possible that you yourself have been granted privileges to the database, but privileges in Oracle can be granted with and without the ability to grant the priviliege on to another user. So if you are not able to grant access you may need to have an administrator do it for you.

Comment: How is your colleague trying to query the tabke - as `select * from fishtable`, or as `select * from smahala.fishtable`? Unles they'vre created a synonym or changed their session's current schema, they will have to include the schema when they refer to the table.

Comment: @Falle1234 - if that was the reason, the OP would get an error when they attempted to grant privileges to the colleague, they wouldn't get "grant succeeded."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your colleague needs to prefix your table with your schema name, otherwise Oracle doesn't know where to look for it, e.g.:

```
select * from smahala.fishtable
```

If they don't do that, and simply try to use:

```
select * from fishtable
```

then Oracle will look for the table in their own schema, and then look for a view, or a private synonym, or a public synonym. Your colleague could create a synonym if they'll be accessing this table a lot (and they don't have their own table with the same name). It's also possible to change their session's current schema, but that will make it harder to see their own objects.

You can read more about [object naming](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223) and [how to refer to objects](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements009.htm#SQLRF51132) in the documentation.

SQL Developer allows you to browse objects in other schemas. If your colleague was connected when you granted the permissions, they can refresh the object list, or disconnect and reconnect. Either way they should then be abke to see your table under your schema.

(Your second grant statement is missing an `on`, and you can't grant permissions across a database link, if that's what you're trying to do.)